Is there a fix for "Option "--coverage" is ambiguous." in PestPHP in Bitbucket pipelines?
Running the custom test in the following configuration results in the message
Option "--coverage" is ambiguous. followed by failure in the pipeline.
image:
  name: timeglitchd/frankenphp-laravel:1.3-php8.4-testing
definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0
      variables:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: "testing"
        MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
        MYSQL_USER: "test_user"
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: "test_user_password"
  caches:
    composer:
      key:
        files:
          - composer.json
          - composer.lock
      path: vendor
  steps:
    - step: &composer-install
        name: Install dependencies
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - composer install --no-progress
    - step: &phpstan
        name: PHPStan
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - vendor/bin/phpstan analyze -c phpstan.neon --memory-limit=1G
    - step: &pint
        name: Pint
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - vendor/bin/pint --test
    - step: &code_coverage
        name: Pest Code Coverage
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - echo 'DB_USERNAME=test_user' >> .env
          - echo 'DB_PASSWORD=test_user_password' >> .env
          - echo 'APP_URL=http://localhost' >> .env
          - echo 'APP_KEY=' >> .env
          - php artisan key:generate
          - php artisan passport:keys
          - vendor/bin/pest --coverage --min=100
        services:
          - mysql
pipelines:
   custom:
    test:
      - step: *composer-install
      - parallel:
          steps:
            - step: *phpstan
            - step: *code_coverage
            - step: *pint

I have found the following issues related to this:

https://github.com/pestphp/pest/issues/94
https://github.com/pestphp/pest/issues/1158

But I'm afraid following the suggestions in that thread had no effect for me.
I've tried adding - export COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 and - composer config allow-plugins.pestphp/pest-plugin before - composer install --no-progress.
Running these commands in a local docker container set up like this works like a charm:
# pipeline_test.Dockerfile

# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.2
FROM timeglitchd/frankenphp-laravel:testing

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

docker run --network=host --name mysql  \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE='testing' \
-e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD='yes' \
-e MYSQL_USER='test_user' \
-e MYSQL_PASSWORD='test_user_password' \
-d mysql/mysql-server:8.0

docker build --memory=1g --memory-swap=1g -t pipeline_test/pipeline_test:latest -f pipeline_test.Dockerfile . &&\
docker run -it --network=host --memory=4g --memory-swap=4g --memory-swappiness=0 --cpus=4 --entrypoint=/bin/bash pipeline_test/pipeline_test:latest

Image is available on https://hub.docker.com/r/timeglitchd/frankenphp-laravel
I think my problem is due to a composer update which prevents scripts from being installed by the root user or the sudo command. Does anyone know how to rewrite my pipeline to work with the new composer version?

Side note: I'd strongly recommend you use custom docker image for your pipeline. These installation steps are eating a lot of your pipeline minutes and it all takes a lot longer that it normally should

@MarcinOrlowski I've updated my question, thank you!
